# How may I restrict accesing apache using server IP address?

Tags: server, apache2, dns

I have a server. I installed and configured Virtualmin/Webmin on it. Also I added three domains and configured almost 100% correct all DNS records.

My big question is how I restrict accessing website through server IP. Or how to redirect the IP to a specific location from my server to load specific files?

Comment: can you provide an example ?

Comment: I have three domains. I've added them to the server ( create virtual hosts, dns records, etc) They work fine. Lets say my domains are a.com b.com and c.com and my server ip is 1.1.1.1 , first time when I added a.com I was also able to access a.com using 1.1.1.1, then after I added b.com, when I was typing 1.1.1.1 into my browser it shows me b.com website, then after I added c.com , when I type 1.1.1.1 I see c.com website. I don't want this to happen. I want 1.1.1.1 to show something else like /var/www/somefolder . Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [virtualhosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) for that. Something along lines

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/ip_address_root
ServerName 123.123.123.123

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

(Example copied from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html))

Alternatively, [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) helps with this. Something like

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.org/you_are_using_ip_address [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to map the ip to localhost in **/etc/hosts**

Comment: That's not going to help at all, unless you do it on all client computers, which might be difficult.